# c# neo4j cypher use regular exp

Tags: c#, regex, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm using the `Neo4j` graph DB with `Neo4jClient`
and I'm trying to execute a search query on nodes, where the result should return a list of nodes that contain a given query string.

I have this working, but it seems inefficient as I'm bringing all the `Groups` back and then filtering. Is there a better way?

```
    internal object SearchGroups(string query)
    {
        var groups = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(g:Groups)")
            .Return(g => g.As<Groups>())
            .Results;
        List<Groups> groupList = new List<Groups>();
        foreach (var item in groups)
        {
            if (item.GroupName.Contains(query))
            {
                groupList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return groupList;
    }
```

I've seen examples that filter using `.Where((Groups g)=> g.GroupName == query)`
but this only returns if it matches, not if it `Contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're mostly there with the tag of `regex` - you have 2 options depending on what you want to do, and what your `query` is. First though - **Please** read the documentation for [`Cypher`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/) and try your queries out in the Admin window (localhost:7474) first, you'll find it hugely beneficial. In particular for this the [`Where`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#query-where-regex) documentation would have helped you a lot.

**Option 1: Regex**

```
var groups = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(g:Groups)")
    .Where("g.GroupName =~ {nameParam}")
    .WithParam("nameParam", string.Format(".*{0}.*", query))
    .Return(g => g.As<Groups>())
    .Results;
```

Cypher for this looks like:

```
MATCH (g:Groups) WHERE g.GroupName =~ '.*<your query text>.*' RETURN g
```

This is using a `regex` - *as a parameter* which will work in the same way as `Contains`. Using `regex` like this is not performant, and it might be better if you can do something like....

**Option 2: Starts With**

This is only applicable *if* you're using `Neo4j 2.3+` *and* your `query` is a `Starts With` type query, but would be significantly faster.

```
var groups = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(g:Groups)")
    .Where((Groups g) => g.GroupName.StartsWith(query))
    .Return(g => g.As<Groups>())
    .Results;
```

Cypher for this looks like:

```
MATCH (g:Groups) WHERE g.GroupName STARTS WITH <your query text> RETURN g
```

**PS**

You really should return `IEnumerable<Groups>`/`ICollection<Groups>`/`IList<Groups>` from your method instead of `object`, and you could also replace your `foreach` with:

```
var groupsList = groups.Where(g => g.GroupName.Contains(query)).ToList();
```

Or just return it:

```
return groups.Where(/*see above*/);
```